# Negative currency data displaying in parenthesis. Minus symbol is missing. Any suggestions?

Tags: currency

In my visualforce page, i am displaying amount data and it is working fine if the amount is a positive number. But if it is negative amount then the data is enclosed in a parentheses. But, i need a minus symbol prefixed in front of the amount like the one given below.

-$16,77,390

I am using the following code on the vf page to display the currency data.

```
        <apex:outputText label="Credit Exposure" id="creditexposure" value="{0,number,currency}">  
            <apex:param value="{!CustCreditInfo.CreditExposure}" />  
        </apex:outputText>
```

It displayed as,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formatting pattern `{0,number,$#,##0.00}` with these sample values:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,$#,##0.00}">  
    <apex:param value="{! 12345.25 }" />  
</apex:outputText>
<br/>
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,$#,##0.00}">  
    <apex:param value="{! 0.25 }" />  
</apex:outputText>
<br/>
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,$#,##0.00}">  
    <apex:param value="{! -12345.25 }" />  
</apex:outputText>
<br/>
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,$#,##0.00}">  
    <apex:param value="{! -0.25 }" />  
</apex:outputText>
<br/>  
</apex:page>
```

produces these output:

```
$12,345.25 
$0.25 
-$12,345.25 
-$0.25
```